# The limit of $f'(x)=b$ implies that $f$ is differentiable at that point

Tags: calculus

if $h$ is a continuous function which is differentiable at all points except "possibly" the point $a$. Then how come $\lim_{x\to a}h'(x)=b$ and then $h$ is differentiable also at $a$ and $h'(a)=b$?

Comment: The question isn't totally clear (please make sure the body of the question is complete independent of the title); but I don't think the assertion is correct. Consider $h(x) = x^2\sin\frac1x$ when $x\ne0$ and $h(0)=0$.

Comment: Did someone really say "$\lim_{x\to a}h'(x)=b$ and then ..." or was it "**if** $\lim_{x\to a}h'(x)=b$ then ..."?